# facebook graph api - search event

Tags: facebook, api, events, search

In the event search, the query searches only by the Event Name:
sample http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=party&type=event

- Is there a way to query the Event Description? Or other fields ?

I tried to use until or since, but i get the same results
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=party&type=event&until=today
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=party&type=event&until=yesterday

- FQL only accept search by event ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search returns the id's for all events returned in the search. Using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=party&type=event&until=today&fields=id  you can loop the id results to https://graph.facebook.com/eventid?access_token=yourapptoken to get array of the event which will include the description, name, image etc;

***Live Sample for Page & Event Search here:*** http://shawnsspace.com/plugins/plugins.searcher.php

**Refer to:** http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

**Example Code:** Assumes PHP-SDK 3.1.1 is installed on page.

**Events** https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event

---

```
  <?php
    $qi = urlencode($_GET['qs']);
        if(!$_GET['qs']){
        $qi = urlencode($_POST['qs']);
            if(!$_POST['qs']){
        $qi = "party";
        }
    }
    $search = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$qi.'&type=event&limit=10');
       foreach ($search as $key=>$value) {
       $i=1;
          foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
          $i++;
          if($fvalue[id]=="h"){
          }else{              
            $id = $fvalue[id];
    $searchResp = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'');
            $name = $searchResp[name];
            $location = $searchResp[location];
           $desc = $searchResp[description];
            $sTime = $searchResp[start_time];
            $eTime = $searchResp[end_time];

               echo $name. '<br />';
               echo $location. '<br />';
               echo $sTime. '<br />';
               echo $eTime. '<br /><hr />';
        }
        };
    };
?>
<form id="getsearch" method="post" action="yourpage.php">
<input type="text" value="" name="qs" id="searchbox" onclick="this.value='';" style="padding: 2px;" size="48">
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="padding: 3px;">
</form>
```

---

Comment: Its good to see you on SO Shawn. You are really fantastic with Facebook so users will be well benefited by you. +1 for detailed answer

Comment: Thank You! Awais, i am happy to see you too.

Comment: "FQL is deprecated after v2.1" source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 1):

The search in Graph API for events is currently limited to the event name only; I don't believe there are plans to change this in the short term, unfortunately